# subdomain archiving

Tags: multisite

I've been trying to figure out if this can be done through Multisite, but I'm pretty new to this concept so please forgive any ignorance.

I'm looking for a way in which my client can easily archive a WP conference site, by year, to subdomains.

In other words:

The site will be set up at http://www.domain.com for the client's 2011 conference. In 2012, the client will use the same templates to set up their 2012 site, but before they do that, they'll want to archive the 2011 site to 2011.domain.com.

As an example, check out evoconference.com. They have their 2010 site linked to from their current 2011 site, and clicking on it brings you to 2010.evoconference.com.

Is there a way I can set this up via multisite? I can set up 2011.domain.com, but how can I make it easy for my client to transfer http://www.domain.com to 2011.domain.com, once they are ready to implement the 2012 site?

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1):

We also covered this in the wordpress.org forums. :) the answer is no. Our sugestion was to make the main site a landing page and set up each year on their subdomains, just like the WordCamp.org site does now.

"archiving" a site in multisite basically shuts it down. (See Network Admin -> Sites) so that's not what you'd want.